Want to create a temp table in Power BI based on user event
I need create or populate a table of 14 rows when the user selects a slicer filter.
I have a Race table with 1 raceID that connects to a runner table of runners in that race joined on the raceID. The Runners connect to a large Fact table of all runners previous runs. I join the Runner table to the FACT table based on Horse - THis is a many to many and will not return the horses to my visual when I put horse in the legend option. If I join on raceID I will only get the times for the current race when I want all historical runs of the horse in that particular race field
Race to Runner(Runners in that race) is 1 to Many
Runner to FACT joining on horse ( as I want the horses history is Many to Many as the runner table will list the horse multiple times but against different RaceID's) The many to many wont populate my Chart. If I join on RaceID to FACT I will only get the horse times for the current race. IF I had a temp tabe just showing the runners for 1 race I could join that to FACT and get the history I want as it woud be a one to many join temprunners to FACT
1/ Can I Create a temp table in DAX with just this races runners that is triggered by a user selecting that race
2/ Or is the Model screwed
I want I visual Line chart that gives historical lines or averages for each runner in that race pulled from the FAct history table. Each runner has multiple rows in the fact table
This will generate when the user selects a particular race

